# 14.04 on new amd computer and ethernet won't work

Tags: 14.04, networking

Network cable works on other computers and a USB wifi will connect, but the lan will not connect to internet.

sudo lshw -c net

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 0c
       serial: fc:aa:14:cb:f1:c3
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:73 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fe100000-fe100fff memory:d2100000-d2103fff
```

card seems to be there.  I have searched for weeks for a solution and no luck. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You could use a more efficient search algorithm. As with ostendali's answer, I found these within seconds (search term: "rtl8111 driver ubuntu"): http://askubuntu.com/questions/126227/12-04-wired-network-doesnt-work-rtl8111-8168b http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1022411 A question: You say it can't reach the Internet, what about your local network? You do get a point or two for testing the cable...

Answer (score 0):

Pls try to provide more info next time, info such as:

```
   uname -a
   ifconfig
   lsmod |grep rtl
```

However, if you just type the chipset/brand of your ethernet interface on network you will find the solution. YYou searched for weeks and i searched for 5 seconds and found everything about it even not knowing the full info.

Pls find the driver for your network card here and install them:

```
   http://www.realtek.com.tw/Downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#2
```

Keep it in mind that you might have some modules loaded already for the interface and you have to blacklist that as it seems obvious that they don't work.